# Import Paypal Library

Tags: android, import, paypal, libraries

I have the paypal library imported but in the integration it seems like it's not added as I am still seeing the errors. I might be importing improperly but I have PayPal_MPL.jar in "libs" folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: u declared paypal activity in manifest?

Comment: I definitely have that added as well.

Comment: can u post the image here?

Comment: I have them added now.

Comment: ok just make sure u hv tick the library in order and export tab in java build path

Comment: post image of order and export tab window also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your problem. In your class path you have added old PayPal MPL library but your source you are using new SDK code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Eclipse`, you should add it using `Right clic` on the `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Add External Jars` -> `Locate file`

Comment: Try building/cleaning the project again. If that doesn't work, create a new project.

Comment: I have. Please see the image above, if that helps.

Comment: When you add external libraries, they should be stored in Referenced Libraries. Private Libraries is just for android-support-v4.jar; libs as well is for android-support-v4.jar

Comment: Your picture does not show the content of the Referenced Libraries folder. In that folder is where the PayPal library should be.

Comment: Move Google Mobile Ads to Referenced Libraries as well, and try cleaning/rebuilding or resetting Eclipse. If that does not work, create a new project from scratch and copy and paste all your classes/layouts/etc again.